# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-material

Senhores, estou tomando este erro ao rodar meu formulario de cadastro..

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
>       at forms.js:3282
>       at forms.js:3222
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at FormGroup.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroup._forEachChild (forms.js:3222)
>       at FormGroup.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroup._checkAllValuesPresent (forms.js:3281)
>       at FormGroup.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroup.setValue (forms.js:3071)
>       at ContactformComponent.push../src/app/contactform/contactform.component.ts.ContactformComponent.ngOnInit (contactform.component.ts:57)
>       at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:9250)
>       at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:10514)
>       at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:10476)

Segue meu código:

```
  contactFrm: FormGroup;

  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
                     private fb: FormBuilder,
                     private _contactService: ContactService,
                     public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ContactlistComponent>) {}  

ngOnInit() {
    // built contact form
    this.contactFrm = this.fb.group({
      //id: [''],
      name:  [''],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      gender: ['', [Validators.required]],
      birth: ['', [Validators.required]],
      techno: ['', [Validators.required]],
      message: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
}
```

html:

```
<form  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(contactFrm)"  [formGroup]="contactFrm">
    <h2>{{data.modalTitle}}</h2>

    <div>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
        <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Name" name="name" formControlName="name">
        <!-- <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon> -->
        <!-- <mat-hint>Hint</mat-hint> -->
        <mat-error *ngIf="formErrors.name">
          {{ formErrors.name }}
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</form>
```

Estou tentando fazer o exemplo deste [site](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/contact-application-using-asp-net-core-web-api-angular-6-0-and-visual-studio-c2/).

Comment: opa, acho que está faltando colocar "ngModel" no seu input do name. Consegue ver se é isso?

Comment: não se é isso, porque no exemplo ele não usa..
estou rodando Angular 6

Answer (score 1):

O erro esta no seguinte html:

```
  <mat-error *ngIf="formErrors.name">
              {{ formErrors.name }}
   </mat-error>
```

vc não deifiniu uma propriedade formErrors.

Answer (score 0):

eu esqueci de colocar esse código no texto do erro..

Eu já tinha posto porém o problema continua..

formErrors = {
    'name': '',
    'email': '',
    'gender': '',
    'birth': '',
    'techno': '',
    'message': ''
  };

Comment: edita a pergunta ja que isso nao resolveu seu problema

Answer (score 0):

Apenas para confirmar, retirei o trecho de código abaixo e mesmo assim o problema ainda persiste...

{{ formErrors.name }}

Sera que não tem algo haver com os pacotes do angular?

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, tente esse trecho de código.

```
<mat-error *ngIf="contactFrm.get('name').errors">
                  {{ contactFrm.get('name').errors.required }}
</mat-error>
```